# BigQuery import "Unexpected" error

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to import a large test file into BigQuery and the import process fail after few hours with

> Unexpected. Please try again.

This is my jobId:
`job_f3d6dbaae8af4aa286ef1d50c12a6`

Could you please take a look?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our import worker hit a CPU usage limit and it was killed. We're upping the limit, but it is possible that it was a corrupted gzip file. I'll update this response when the limit has been raised.

I realize that may be painful for a large file, but can you retry with an uncompressed file? If you have an uncompressed file and set allow_quoted_newlines to false, then the import will be done in parallel and should up to 100x faster.

Comment: It worked with the uncompressed 70Gb file and importing with the allow_quoted_newlines=false was really fast!

Comment: The gzip file seems to be OK. Gzip -t does not complain. Here is the link: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/staq-events/events-100k-1.csv.gz